# Substitute in sed not changing files

Tags: unix, sed

Apologies if this has been covered before, I had a search but couldn't find anything. I realise this is probably a simple error, but I'm currently learning UNIX.

I've been trying to do a sed substitution but every time I've tried the command just seems to print out the files and not substitute anything?

The command in question is:

```
find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sed 's/<name>development<\/name>/<name>releases<\/name>/g' {} \;
```

After I run this command, if I try to find and grep for `<name>development<\/name>` it still returns results. Why?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use this command :  find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/<name>development<\/name>/<name>releases<\/name>/g' {} \;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not actually editing the file--just printing the edited version to `stdout`. Use sed's `-i` flag:

> `-i[SUFFIX]` 
>   `--in-place[=SUFFIX]` 
>       This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
>      `sed` does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
>      this file rather than to the standard output.(1).

So:

```
find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sed -i  's/<name>development<\/name>/<name>releases<\/name>/g' {} \;
```

You can also use a different character besides `/` if you don't want to have to escape them:

```
find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sed -i  's@<name>development</name>@<name>releases</name>@g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)